# guzzlehttp/guzzle Conflicting With Important Packages

Tags: composer-php, guzzle

I have a `coinbase/coinbase-commerce` package in my project that requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0|~6.0` and it's satisfiable by these versions `guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, ..., 5.3.4, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.8]`.

I'm now trying to merge my project with a laravel 10 project (the only version I can use in my circumstance) but laravel 10 requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0`.

Here's the full error message I get when I ran `composer update`:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
> Root composer.json requires coinbase/coinbase-commerce 1.0.11 -> satisfiable by coinbase/coinbase-commerce[1.0.11].
> coinbase/coinbase-commerce 1.0.11 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0|~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, ..., 5.3.4, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).

I added `--with-all-dependencies` but still got the same error message. How can I install the new entries I made in my composer.json file without composer checking dependency conflicts for `coinbase/coinbase-commerce`? I'm open to ignoring updates for coinbase commerce but I don't know the best and safest way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found a workaround. It turns out coinbase/coinbase-commerce is no longer actively maintained but I found a fork that created support for guzzle ^7.0. Here's how it was resolved...

In my composer.json file the package was required like this:

```
"require": {
    "coinbase/coinbase-commerce": "^1.0"
}
```

Edited it to:

```
"require": {
    "coinbase/coinbase-commerce": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:IceQ1337/coinbase-commerce-php"
    }
]
```